# Javascript scroll function slow, lots of "Timer Fired: onloadwff.js:310" weasel events in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug a page which is acting a little slow in Chrome, think it might be an issue with the following javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function navScroll(distance){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scrollTop;
      if(distance){
        scrollTop = distance;
      }else{
        scrollTop = 150;
      }
      if($(window).scrollTop() >= scrollTop) {
        if(!($('#mainNav').hasClass('showNav'))) {
          $('#mainNav').addClass('showNav');
        }
      } else {
        if($('#mainNav').hasClass('showNav')) {
          $('#mainNav').removeClass('showNav');
        }
      }
    });
  }

  if($('.header-image-base').length){
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    $('.header-image-base').css('height', windowHeight);
    navScroll(windowHeight);
  }else{
    navScroll();
  }
});
```

When I look in Chrome's console's 'timeline' panel, and press record, this is what I see:

[image]

Any ideas what is happening here? I can't find any references to this on google and no idea how to remedy it.

Comment: it is just events log not the issue

Comment: The script in the log seems to be a part of a chrome-extension( I guess this: https://lastpass.com/ ).

Answer (score 39):

Your page is slow most likely because you’re attaching a handler to the window scroll event—this is not a good practice as explained below:

> It’s a very, very, bad idea to attach handlers to the window scroll event. Depending upon the browser the scroll event can fire a lot and putting code in the scroll callback will slow down any attempts to scroll the page (not a good idea). Any performance degradation in the scroll handler(s) as a result will only compound the performance of scrolling overall. Instead it’s much better to use some form of a timer to check every X milliseconds OR to attach a scroll event and only run your code after a delay (or even after a given number of executions – and then a delay). ([source](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter))

Your screenshot shows that onloadwff.js is located at `chrome-extension://hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd` which means it’s part of the LastPass extension — as seen below. So it’s probably not related to your performance issue.

[image: screenshot]

([archived screenshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20140506182528/https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mr0Gp.png))

Link - [https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lastpass-free-password-ma/**hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lastpass-free-password-ma/hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @summea, added screenshot and link to archived screenshot.

Comment: @Ayush, I believe this answers the question and I can't comment on the original post since I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: thanks for these clues ... turns out its lastpass trying to inject its icon into the usr/pwd fields ... so just need to turn off lastpass for given website

... lastpass > account settings > Never URLs > Add > Never Show context Icons > your.domain.com > Add

... then logout of lastpass plugin in chrome and log back in again

... and the website you want to continue developing needs to be opened in a new chrome window before lastpass plugin starts respecting the rules and leaving it the heck alone ... a new tab just doesn't cut it

Comment: @pulkitsinghal Odd, I did all those steps and the onloadwff.js file still seems to be causing the 120ms script to run on my site. Maybe Chrome needs to be restarted entirely in my case, for some reason. (which I don't want to do right now because of stuff open, but I'll check it again later after a restart)

Comment: I just disabled Lastpass and my performance issues went away.